# What was the hedge the LORD made around Job? (1:10)

Tags: hebrew, job

What is the meaning of "made a hedge" in this verse?

Does the Septuagint translation provide any additional insight into the meaning?

> Job 1:10 NKJ "Have You not ***made a hedge*** around him, around his household, 
>   and around all that he has on every side? You have blessed the work of his 
>   hands, and his possessions have increased in the land."

Job 1:10 Septuagint 
οὐ σὺ περιέφραξας τὰ ἔξω αὐτοῦ καὶ τὰ ἔσω τῆς οἰκίας αὐτοῦ καὶ τὰ ἔξω 
πάντων τῶν ὄντων αὐτῷ κύκλῳ τὰ ἔργα τῶν χειρῶν αὐτοῦ εὐλόγησας καὶ τὰ 
κτήνη αὐτοῦ πολλὰ ἐποίησας ἐπὶ τῆς γῆς

Job 1:10 Masoretic
הֲלֹֽא־את שַׂכְתָּ בַעֲדֹו וּבְעַד־בֵּיתֹו וּבְעַד
כָּל־אֲשֶׁר־לֹו מִסָּבִיב מַעֲשֵׂה יָדָיו בֵּרַכְתָּ וּמִקְנֵהוּ פָּרַץ בָּאָֽרֶץ׃

Does the following inform further on defining this?

Authorized Version (KJV) Translation Count — Total: 3

- make a hedge  (Job 1:10)
- hedge (Hosea 2:6 (Heb 2:8))
- fence (Job 10:11)

Gesenius's  Lexicon: "the same phrase is also used in a bad way, 'to stop up the way before anyone'"

Answer (score -8, accepted):

The Old Covenant *"hedge*"  that Job had in operation in his life, is comparable to the New Covenant 'Shield of Faith'.

(for a modern example of 'hedge of protection' see  http://www.daystar.com/ondemand/video/?video=3629869651001
roll in to 15:07 for "protective hedge"
John Paul Jackson teaches on prophetic dreams and visions from the Holy Spirit today.)

I believe these two are the same type of thing. The protection of the Lord that surrounded Job and 'hedged him in', is the same protection that New Testament believers can experience if they operate inside the same principles of faith and believing in the Lord answering their prayer requests for the protection.

> Ephesians 6:16 New English Translation (NET Bible)
>   16 and in all of this, by ***taking up the shield of faith with which you can extinguish all the flaming arrows of the evil one.***

The Roman shield that Paul would have referred to was a large 3 ft. tall piece of wood, that was about 3 feet wide as well. It could be used as an offensive and well as defensive weapon.

> Hebrews 11:1
>   **Now faith is the substance of things hoped for, the evidence of things not seen.**

This verse calls faith an actual 'substance', as well as an initial 'evidence' of things that the physical eye cannot see, but is yet real; in actual fact the verse is calling the fact that real faith (the verb) exists, as 'the answer', meaning 'real faith' will cause the answer to manifest, because it is calling 'real faith' (verb) as proof and evidence that things not yet seen are still happening, although the physical eye cannot yet see them, they are still there and still real.

The old covenant hedge that surrounded and protected Job and caused him to increase in the blessing of the Lord, is the same 'shield of faith' operating in the new covenant, providing supernatural protection and the blessing of the Lord.

It appears in the life of Paul in Acts 28:1-6.

> Ac 28:1] NIV Once safely on shore, we found out that the island was called Malta. [2] The islanders showed us unusual kindness. They built a fire and welcomed us all because it was raining and cold. [3] Paul gathered a pile of brushwood and, as he put it on the fire, a viper, driven out by the heat, fastened itself on his hand. [4] When the islanders saw the snake hanging from his hand, they said to each other, "This man must be a murderer; for though he escaped from the sea, Justice has not allowed him to live." [5] ***But Paul shook the snake off into the fire and suffered no ill effects.*** [6] The people expected him to swell up or suddenly fall dead, but after waiting a long time and seeing nothing unusual happening to him, they changed their minds and said he was a god.

This snake was a known poisonous viper, deadly to all, yet it's bite did not effect the Apostle Paul. This is the shield of faith or the hedge of the old covenant, in operation.

According to the Bible The shield or hedge operates by trusting God will give it to you when you ask, only when you actually believe He will do it (this is the definition of faith the verb), then the life of obedience must be adhered to, and or repentance when the person misses it. As well, faith must operate, faith in God and in His protection. Fear (fear=unbelief) can break the shield down, or cause a breach in the hedge. Fear is the antithesis of faith, and operates by bringing things into reality as well, only the flip side of what would be desired.

The Hebrew youths who were thrown in to the furnace fire operated in faith in God's protection and were saved by it.

> Daniel 3:17-18
>    If that is the case,(if you plan to throw us in the furnace) our God whom we serve is able to deliver us from the burning fiery furnace, ***and He WILL deliver us from your hand,*** O king. But if not (even if you decide not to burn us), let it be known to you, O king, that we do NOT serve your gods, NOR will we worship the gold image which you have set up.

The Israelites in the desert operated by it and were saved from snake bites by looking at the bronze serpent, and believing (faith in God's words) they would be saved, as they were instructed by God to do.(and they were saved, everyone that looked)

Another reference to this hedge or shield in the new testament is in:

Jesus speaking -

> Luke 10:19 (KJV)
>   19 **Behold, I give unto you power to tread on serpents and scorpions, and over all the power of the enemy: and *nothing shall by any means hurt you*.**

Jesus speaking -

> MARK 16:17-18 NKJ 
>   17 "**And these signs will follow those who believe: In My name they will cast out demons; they will speak with new tongues; 
>   18 "they will take up serpents; and if they drink anything deadly, it will by no means hurt them; they will lay hands on the sick, and they will recover."**

Answer (score 0):

The protection is called a “hedge” by Satan and one should be cautious in presuming Satan is accurately describing the protection the LORD provides.

The protection should be understood by Scripture:

> 1 He who dwells in the shelter of the Most High
>       will abide in the shadow of the Almighty.
>   2 I will say to the LORD, “My refuge and my fortress,
>       my God, in whom I trust.”
>   3 For he will deliver you from the snare of the fowler
>       and from the deadly pestilence.
>   4 He will cover you with his pinions,
>       and under his wings you will find refuge;
>       his faithfulness is a shield and buckler.
>   5 You will not fear the terror of the night,
>       nor the arrow that flies by day,
>   6 nor the pestilence that stalks in darkness,
>       nor the destruction that wastes at noonday.
>   7 A thousand may fall at your side,
>       ten thousand at your right hand,
>       but it will not come near you.
>   8 You will only look with your eyes
>       and see the recompense of the wicked.
>   9 Because you have made the LORD your dwelling place—
>       the Most High, who is my refuge —
>   10 no evil shall be allowed to befall you,
>       no plague come near your tent.
>   11 For he will command his angels concerning you
>       to guard you in all your ways.
>   12 On their hands they will bear you up,
>       lest you strike your foot against a stone.
>   13 You will tread on the lion and the adder;
>       the young lion and the serpent you will trample underfoot.
>   14 “Because he holds fast to me in love, I will deliver him;
>       I will protect him, because he knows my name.
>   15 When he calls to me, I will answer him;
>       I will be with him in trouble;
>       I will rescue him and honor him.
>   16 With long life I will satisfy him
>       and show him my salvation.”
>   (Psalm 91 ESV)

"He will command His angels concerning you." The LORD's protection emanates from Him and is under His control (His angels). This is what Satan calls a "hedge" which misrepresents the protection as a static physical structure.

While the LORD's response to Satan can be seen as giving Satan permission to test Job, a more accurate analysis considers how Job is deceived by Satan:

> For the thing that I fear comes upon me... (Job 3:25 ESV)
>
> for God gave us a spirit not of fear... (2 Timothy 1:7 ESV)

Fear is **a spirit** not from God; Job's fear was **a spirit** not from God. While the LORD was restraining Satan and his spiritual powers of darkness, keeping them away from Job, Job was effectively inviting them in.

Thus, Satan's confrontation with the LORD is over the continued protection. In other words Satan is saying "Job has accepted my spirit of fear. Why are you still protecting him?"

Satan says the LORD has a "hedge" denying him access to Job, in reality Job has (unknowingly) allowed Satan into his life. Since Job's association with Satan is ongoing, the LORD loosens the restraint in one sense and yet tightens it in another:

> And the Lord said to Satan, “Behold, all that he has is in your hand. Only against him do not stretch out your hand.”... (Job 1:12 ESV)

In reality, Satan wants to kill Job (John 10:10). The LORD does not stop protecting Job. Instead, using Satan's terminology, the LORD tightens the hedge: now it surrounds only Job. Or, using the terminology of Psalm 91, the angels which had been protecting Job's "estate" are now protecting only Job.

Answer (score -1):

It seems though at sometimes with God's discretion He can pull down the hedge of protection as He did with Job. Job was described by God to Satan,

> Hast thou considered my servant Job, that there is none like him in the earth, a perfect and an upright man, one that feareth God, and escheweth evil?
>   -- Job 1:8

So, it did not appear to be of any particular sin of Job that the suk was pulled down.

The lesson here is that God can do whatever He pleases. He may protect, He may for some unknown reason pull down that protection.

Comment: Hi, Stone Palatin. I've done a simple edit to make your answer more readable. Welcome to BH.SE!

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange Stone Palatin, thanks for contributing! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)

Comment: I've edited to remove the prescriptive language. This is not a Christian site. Answers should describe the text without issuing prescriptive statements to readers.